# Neighborhood of Real Numbers

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

If $x_1, x_2, x_3 ,\dots, x_n$ are disjoint real numbers then prove that there exists $r > 0$ such that $B(x_i , r)$ are mutually disjoint neighbourhoods of $x_1,\dots ,x_n$ respectively.

How to prove this?

Answer (score 1):

Among all distances between two of these points, one distance is the smallest. That's where you use the fact that there are only finitely many.

Let $r$ be half of that smallest distance. Than any two of those points are at a distance at least $2r$ from each other. If the distance from $x_i$ to $x_j$ is not less than $2r$, then the neighborhoods of radius $r$ about those points don't overlap. Common sense tells you that, but so does the triangle inequality: Suppose some point $y$ is in both neighborhoods.  Then $d(y,x_i)<r$ and $d(y,x_j)<r$, so $d(x_i,x_j) \le d(x_i,y) + d(y,x_j) < r+ r = 2r \le d(x_i,x_j)$, i.e. $d(x_i,x_j)<d(x_i,x_j),$ and that's a contradiction.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck : That prescription is about as far from being an absolute as any normative rule ever gets. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

It is intuitively obvious; your question would be how to write out the obviousness formally.

Let $r := \min_{1 \leq j \leq n-1} |x_{j+1} - x_{j}|/4$. Then $N(x_{j}, r) \cap N(x_{i}, r)$ is empty for all $i \neq j$.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little please, I'm sorry I do not follow

Comment: The proof is for 4 marks

Comment: Please help me with this!

Comment: @user388914, Ha, guess what, to hint such a question without the OP showing some previous works on it is the upper bound... :) Take it as a hint and try to figure it out yourself. It would be better for you in the long run. Good luck :).

Comment: please help me with this question please

Comment: there is no upper or lower bound mentioned in this chapter sir

Comment: The term "upper bound" is used figuratively, which means that it is not encouraged here to directly help doing people's homework :). I understand you might be frustrated now. But you are better than this; cheer up!

Comment: I have an exam tomorrow please just help me with this I won't post anything here without showing work from next time

Comment: I promise I will show my work from next time I really do not understand how to solve this question N

Comment: For example, suppose $n =3$ and $x_{1} = 1$ and $x_{2} = 2$ and $x_{3} = 4$. Then $(x_{2}-x_{1})/4 = 1/4$ and $(x_{3} - x_{2})/4 = 1/2$. The former is the lesser one, and you've got disjoint balls of radius equal to the number and centers $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}$. Sometimes geometrically considering a problem would be helpful.